# .Net - remove chars from string to First Uppercase char

Tags: regex, string, linq, char, uppercase

How to remove chars from string to first Uppercase char ?

**For example**

**String 1** : 101;#Kristina Johnson --> I want only **Kristina Johnson**

**String 2** : 77;#George Menson ---> I want Only  **George Menson**

How to do this ?

Comment: is you tried anything ?

Comment: .SkipWhile(p => !Char.isUpper(p))

Comment: I tried this, but remove whiteSpace...  --- > var onlyLettersEditor = new String(editor.Where(Char.IsLetter).ToArray());

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try like this

```
var result = new String(s.SkipWhile(p => !Char.IsUpper(p)).ToArray());
```

where `s` is `string s = "101;#Kristina Johnson";`

so output will be `Kristina Johnson`

Comment: Happy to help you :)

Comment: @Gohyu: That is exactly what I suggested in my comment and you said it does not work.

Answer (score 2):

To remove the beginning of a string up to the first uppercase letter, use a regex like

```
Regex.Replace(str, @"^\P{Lu}+", "")
```

Pattern means:

- `^` - string start
- `\P{Lu}+` - one or more characters other than an uppercase letter.

Answer (score 1):

Try this `.*?([A-Z].*)` regex and replace with $0 (or $1, I'm not sure about that regex-implementation), or just get the first match in that string.
`.*?` gets all chars up to the first uppercase char (matches everything, but as few times as possible).
`([A-Z].*)` is the capture-group, beginning with the first uppercase char.

[Try this here](https://regex101.com/r/wW0jZ7/1)

Comment: Try this with multiline input. It does not support Unicode letters either.